# Usage of overrides in the State design pattern

Tags: design-patterns, conventions

Imagine a situation where out of 5 state implementation classes the implementation of a method only differs on 2 of them (i.e. 3/5 share the same implementation for a particular method).

This situation can be handled in a couple of ways when the generic State is an abstract class rather than an interface:

1. The abstract state class defines the method as abstract and *all* concrete subclasses have to implement it
2. The class defines the method fully and it is only overridden in the subclasses where the implementation differs from the majority

It seems to me like the first approach requires more maintenance while the second approach is less explicit.
What are the advantages and disadvantages of these two approaches? Is there a conventional approach to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trade-offs in the options you've provided really amount to measures of convenience and communication. You should consider your approach in the context of what a developer will encounter (refactor) 6 months from now when they implement a new subclass or refactor existing work.

- If you put a concrete implementation in your base class, you're effectively saying 'This is the default behavior' and all classes that override that method are Exceptions To The Rule. This is risky imho since it can be overlooked and result in bugs that are hard to track down on some platforms like ruby, scala, or even python.  There's a good argument to be made that methods on abstract classes should be sealed where ever possible.
- Leaving the method as abstract communicates that the intention and use is open to interpretation by the inheriting class. This approach can be supplemented through the use of static functions or helper libraries.
- A hybrid approach I've used is to have the base implementation throw an exception when called, signaling to the developer that they are required to provide an implementation while at the same time, not halting development too much.

For my money, I prefer the latter cases. It requires the developer to give considered thought to what the method is actually supposed to achieve and it helps to remove any 'surprises' that might occur e.g. "I didn't know it would call that!". Regardless of your approach, be sure to use a judicious application of TDD. Not just to make sure your logic works, but to act as a fail-safe if logic elsewhere changes, breaking your pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Is this the only method that differs? The true power of OOP shines when methods need to change together.

Consider an interface that only defines the method(s) that change. It would only need three implementing classes. Now your five implementation classes can use that interface to show what they need to use. The five delegate any calls to method(s) to whichever of the 3 they got handed when they were built.

Done this way there is no need for inheritance or duplicated code. Just a constructor expecting something that implements this interface. See [favor composition over inheritance](https://www.google.com/search?q=favor+composition+over+inheritance).

As for the [State Design Pattern](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/state-design-pattern/), done this way you are perfectly free to have 5 states. 3 of them will have the same behaviors for some methods.

Might not feel exactly like the State Pattern. It is. It just has a little Strategy Pattern hiding inside some composition.

As for the principal this follows, it’s: separate things that change from things that stay the same.